# how to improve lag of data viewer in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a large dataset with more than 100 columns. In dataview for R studio, scrolling up and down for the data is really slow and lags. How can improve the lag problem? and how can i limit the number of columns to view.

Thank you

Comment: Are you referring to the data viewer in Rstudio? If so, please edit your question tags to include this.

Comment: Yes i am referring to data viewer in R studio

Comment: `View(mydata[1:100, 1:5])` in order to limit it's size (first 100 rows and first 5 columns)

Answer (score 3):

try `utils::View( mydata )`... And (of course) you can also easily subset the data you want to view, like `utils::View( mydata[1:1000,] )` for viewing the first 1,000 rows.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped a lot.